# android:take in account xml values

Tags: android, xml

I am making an app in which i have to send xml to server to validate the user and password and in return i am getting response , if username and password is correct then OK else INVALID .Now my question is how to take value from xml and login to next screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Extra` in your intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("some_key", "My interesting string");
```

Then in the other activity you can retrieve it like this:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("some_key");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SAXParser](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser) or [DomParser](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser) .

if XML is Small , parse it directly from string response .